# Not able to locate element on a modal pop up window in Selenium

Tags: selenium, modal-dialog, webdriver

I am automating a webpage using Selenium Webdriver. I am not able to click a button a modal pop up window using simple element locator method.

Example:

- open www.walmart.com
- enter tv in the search box.
- select some tv and click "Add to Cart"
- Now a pop up window comes where "Checkout" button is located. I need to click on this "checkout" button.

I tried switchTo() windowhandle, I tried switchTo() frame but nothing worked.

Comment: You should show some work at least. It's against SO policy to ask this kind of help without showing any work from your side

Comment: ok. code i wrote to click on checkout web elementdriver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='PACCheckoutBtn']")).click();

Comment: when i inspect the window it shows <div class="Modal-inner FlexStack">

please let me know if i need to peovide more information. I was not able to upload image as SO did not allow me to upload image.

Comment: @Nidhi  Please use the edit link under your question to provide more information rather than putting it in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This website is very slow and has loading issue. So, I suggest you to use [Explicit wait](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp) for each findElement. I have written the following script and works perfectly

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();        

driver.get("http://www.walmart.com/");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("[placeholder='Search']")))
        .sendKeys("TV");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".searchbar-submit.js-searchbar-submit")).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("#tile-container>div>a>img")))
        .get(0).click();        
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("WMItemAddToCartBtn"))).click();
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("PACCheckoutBtn"))).click();
```

Comment: awesomeeeeeeeeee....... it worked :D . Thanks soooo much Saifur. so basically it is the timing issue... when I was using plain    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='PACCheckoutBtn']")).click();      it did not work.  But when I just changed the line to include wait, it worked. I just changed my line to                                                          WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20); 
  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("PACCheckoutBtn"))).click();

Comment: Yes, it is timing issue. Glad to help