# How to find elements of a modal pop up window with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, modal-dialog, webdriver

I am using Selenium webdriver with firefox to download real states data from a website. Once the inputs are entered a pop up window will ask to either select `'Cancel'` or `'Save File'`.

The problem is that I'm not able to find how to `'click'` these buttons. I know it is already the current window in my driver because I am able to change the [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPECN.png) position.

If I do`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*')`, this is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-131-e87e382e3fb9>", line 1, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*')

File
"/home/rcortez/anaconda2/envs/webscraper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
line 295, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)

File
"/home/rcortez/anaconda2/envs/webscraper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
line 756, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']

File
"/home/rcortez/anaconda2/envs/webscraper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
line 238, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

File
"/home/rcortez/anaconda2/envs/webscraper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py",
line 193, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

NoSuchWindowException: No such content frame; perhaps the listener was not registered
```

I've searched on the web for solutions and most of them mention switching to alert, `driver.switch_to_alert().accept()`. This is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-142-bd939a2be33d>", line 1, in <module>
    driver.switch_to_alert().accept()

File
"/home/rcortez/anaconda2/envs/webscraper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/alert.py",
line 81, in accept
    self.driver.execute(Command.ACCEPT_ALERT)

File
"/home/rcortez/anaconda2/envs/webscraper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py",
line 238, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)

File
"/home/rcortez/anaconda2/envs/webscraper/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py",
line 193, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

NoAlertPresentException: No tab modal was open when attempting to get the dialog text
```

This issue is very similar to [Not able to locate element on a modal pop up window : selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685447/not-able-to-locate-element-on-a-modal-pop-up-window-selenium), but I don't understand how the accepted answer there was able to find the selectors.

Any ideas how to solve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide some more information as: 1. Provide the relevant HTML DOM. 2. Can you share the URL incase it's a public url?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access to file download dialog in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176348/access-to-file-download-dialog-in-firefox)

Comment: The URL is https://qpublic.schneidercorp.com/

Comment: Once the site is updated with your input data (address, name) if you scroll down, a Recent Sales button will allow you to download a file.